# ViewPager is not going to the normal way

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I implemented a **`ViewPager` using `FragmentStatePageAdapter` cause it's a dynamic ViewPager and it's working normal when it creates itself**. 
Each fragment have a `TextView` and Two `Button`s, each button changes `Textview` `Size` to Big and to Small.

Parameters are saved on a SharedPreference instance. So, technically when I slide to the next fragment it show the TextView with the new Pararmeters applied, and Indeed it works and it shows the new size, **it's working fine**.

I have three fragments and **the problem begin** when I'm try to slide between fragment 0 to fragment 1 to refresh new parameters. 
On method:

`public Fragment getItem(int position)`

**For some reason it gets the `position` 2 and yeah, it shows the `fragment` 1 without changes, and when I slide to `Fragment` Two, it shows the new changes I did on `Fragment` 0**. In the same way, when I slide back to `Fragment` 1 method `getItem` get the `position` 0 and begin to apply new changes, but never changes the `Fragment` 1.

I tried to add a new `fragment` so now are four `fragments` (0,1,2,3), and when I jump between 3 to 2, it begin to refresh information on Fragment 1.

**I detected method getItem (int position) returns odd fragments.**

Why it is working as this way?

**Suppose it would return 0-1-2-3 instead 0-2-4, 1-3-5.**

**Part of my Code**

```
    posicionlist = pref.getInt("sel_psalm", 0);
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_psalm_fullscreen);
 // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        loadFragment();

    private void loadFragment(){
         mPager.setCurrentItem(posicionlist);
             }
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {



                Fragment fragmento = new FragmentSalmosFull();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString(FragmentSalmosFull.TIT_FRAG, Tsalmos.get(position).getName());
                args.putString(FragmentSalmosFull.ESP_FRAG, Tsalmos.get(position).getEspFile());
                args.putString(FragmentSalmosFull.HEB_FRAG, Tsalmos.get(position).getHebFile());
                args.putString(FragmentSalmosFull.FON_FRAG, Tsalmos.get(position).getFonFile());
                args.putInt(FragmentSalmosFull.LANG_SELECTED_FRAG, selectedLang);
                fragmento.setArguments(args);

                return fragmento;

            }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabaux;
        }


    }
```

public static class FragmentSalmosFull extends Fragment {

```
    public static final String TIT_FRAG = "section_name";
    public static final String ESP_FRAG = "section_esp";
    public static final String HEB_FRAG = "section_heb";
    public static final String FON_FRAG = "section_fon";
    public static final String LANG_SELECTED_FRAG = "language_selected";

    Context contextu;

    private Typeface tf, to;
    private int sizefont;
    private int posicionlang;
    private TextView tvcontenido;
    private TextView tvesp;
    private TextView tvheb;
    private TextView tvfon;
    Button mas;
    Button menos;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    Editor editor;
    int tamanofinal = 0;

    Boolean clickesp = false;
    Boolean clickheb = false;
    Boolean clickfon = false;




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentsalmosfull, container, false);

        final Bundle args = getArguments();
        contextu = getActivity();
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "Arvil_Sans.ttf");
        to = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "AvantGardEF-Book.ttf");
        pref = contextu.getSharedPreferences("MyPref",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = pref.edit();
        sizefont = pref.getInt("font_size", 22);
        posicionlang = pref.getInt("posLang", 0);

        // Setear el texto

        TextView title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.titulo_salmo);
        title.setText(args.getString(TIT_FRAG));

        tvcontenido = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contenido_salmo);
        tvcontenido.setTypeface(to);
        tvesp = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contenido_esp);
        tvesp.setTypeface(tf);
        tvheb = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contenido_heb);
        tvheb.setTypeface(tf);
        tvfon = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contenido_fon);
        tvfon.setTypeface(tf);
        mas = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_aumenta);
        mas.setTypeface(tf);
        menos = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_reduce);
        menos.setTypeface(tf);


        tvesp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tvesp.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9400D3"));
                tvesp.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                tvheb.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                tvheb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tvfon.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                tvfon.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                lee(args.getString(ESP_FRAG));
                if(!clickesp){
                    clickesp = true;
                    editor.putInt("posLang", 0);
                    editor.commit();
                }else{
                    clickesp = false;
                }
            }
        });
        tvheb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tvheb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9400D3"));
                tvheb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                tvesp.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                tvesp.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tvfon.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                tvfon.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                lee(args.getString(HEB_FRAG));

                if(!clickheb){
                    clickheb = true;
                    editor.putInt("posLang",1);
                    editor.commit();
                }else{
                    clickheb = false;
                }

            }
        });
        tvfon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                tvfon.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#9400D3"));
                tvfon.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                tvesp.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                tvesp.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tvheb.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                tvheb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                lee(args.getString(FON_FRAG));

                if(!clickfon){
                    clickfon = true;
                    editor.putInt("posLang",2);
                    editor.commit();
                }else{
                    clickfon = false;
                }
            }
        });

        mas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (sizefont < 40) {
                    sizefont++;
                    tvcontenido.setTextSize(sizefont);
                    tamanofinal = sizefont;
                    editor.putInt("font_size", sizefont);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
        menos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (sizefont > 18) {
                    sizefont--;
                    tvcontenido.setTextSize(sizefont);
                    tamanofinal = sizefont;
                    editor.putInt("font_size", sizefont);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });

        if(args.getInt(LANG_SELECTED_FRAG)!= posicionlang) {
            loadSelection(posicionlang);
            System.out.println("Hizo click en alguno de los Languages" + posicionlang + "Posicion Original" + args.getInt(LANG_SELECTED_FRAG));
        }
         else{
            loadSelection(args.getInt(LANG_SELECTED_FRAG));

            }

            return rootView;

    }
```

Thank you everyone. I'm new on Android as you can see.

Comment: we cannot help you without seeing the source code of fragment and adapter

Comment: Sorry, I added my code. Thank you.